# getting error Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-plaid-link' in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I have installed `react-plaid-link` module, still i am getting this error Module not found: `Can't resolve 'react-plaid-link'` , in mu `ubuntu 18.04` os, can anyone please help me why i am getting this error again and again even after installing that module,I am using `npm -v 6.11.2` and `node -v 10.13.0`

Comment: try `npm cache clean -f`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

try to update node and npm and  uninstall this react-plaid-link and install it again